# select values from array till specified value in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I get data like below

z = 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0

T = 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000

I want to pick 'T' data till a certain value of 'z', say 0.6. I want to have a generalized method where every time I can specify  value of 'z' and it can return the z as well as T. Next step is I want to pick data in between the two z values that I specify. Say z=0.1 and z=0.7 and it should give me 100 to 700 along with z values. Can someone suggest something in Python? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are reaching for `zip()` together with `itertools.takewhile()` and `itertools.dropwhile()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have a generalized method where every time I can specify value of 'z' and it can return the z as well as T.

```
def getT(z_value):
    return [z_value,T[z.index(z_value)]]
```

Example use:

```
>> getT(0.1)
[0.1, 100]
```

where the first value is the z and the second value is the corresponding T.

> Next step is I want to pick data in between the two z values that I specify. Say z=0.1 and z=0.7 and it should give me 100 to 700 along with z values.

```
def getTbounded(lowerz,upperz):
    return [z[z.index(lowerz):z.index(upperz)+1],
           T[z.index(lowerz):z.index(upperz)+1]]
```

Example use:

```
>> getTbounded(0.1,0.7)
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7], [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]]
```

where the first list is the z values and the second list is the T values.